# Texmaker/TeXstudio insert label

Tags: cross-referencing, texmaker, texstudio

Is there any way to invoke the list of labels (and then select one for insertion in the text) using either TEXmaker or TEXstudio?

As far as I can tell, in TEXmaker you only get the list of labels when you use and autocomplete command that uses the keyword #label# (for example, an autocompletion defined as `\ref{#label#}` results in a suggestion for each label defined in the document (`\ref{labe1}`, `\ref{labe2}`, etc...) when autocompletion pops up. However, I found no way of invoking a pop-up (or the like) with just the list of defined labels. It is true that the labels are listed in the document structure on the left pane, but apparently they can only be used for navigation, and cannot be dragged or cut/pasted into the text.

In TEXstudio at least you can right click on a label on the list, and you can "insert" it. However, this is still not as convenient as invoking a list of labels while typing.

To put the request in a more specific context, her is why I am interested in this. I was using TEXmaker and heppily and abundantly using the `\ref{#label#}` autocompletion. At some point, however, I started using the cleveref package. Since `\cref` was not present in the autocompletion list, I went ahead and defined `\cref{#label#`. When I start typeing `\cref` I now get a list with one entry for every label I have. Wonderful.
However, `\cref` can also accept more than one argument (`\cref{label1,label2,label3,...}`), and it would be extremely convenient if after selecting the entry corresponding to label1, I could just type a comma and invoke a list of all labels, so that I could select the next one, and so on... however, I did not find anything that came even close to that in TEXmaker.
As mentioned, TEXstudio is slightly more convenient because you can right click on a label in the document structure and insert it, but this is still not very quick.

Any suggestion? Is seems such an useful feature, that I feel like I'm missing a very obvious way of doing it, in which case I apologize (but would still appreciate to know how!).

Comment: This is currently an open enhancement on the TeXmaker issues board. https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=509&q=label&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary

Comment: TeXstudio: This is not supported in the current version (2.9.4), but has already been implemented and will be available from the next release on.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Goo dto know I wasn't the only one looking for this functionality! :-)

Comment: @Tim: I am now on TexStudio 2.11.0, but I still can't find this function, either in the program or in the documentation. Has it not been implemented yet? Are we talking about two different things? Or am I just inept at finding it? :-)

Comment: The completer reopens when your cursor is within a citation command and you type a comma.

Comment: @Tim: I see, thanks. However that seems to work only for bibliographic citations, not "\ref" commands. Also, automation is welcome, but a good old shortcut for bringing up the autocompletion would be more flexible... I guess I'll bring this up in the feature request tracker (if it doesn't exist already).

Comment: The standard`\ref` does not allow for multiple enties. Therefore TXS does not either. Support for multiple entries in `\cref` has been implemented since 2.10.0. Also, you should not have to define it yourself. Defining yourself may lead to incorrect or limited behavior if you don't follow the [rules for cwl files](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html#CWLDESCRIPTION). You can always bring up the completer by `<Ctrl>+<Space>`.

Comment: Thanks again. I am a bit ashamed. Somehow I was convinced that multiple autocompletion on the \cref command was not working, but I just tried and obviously it does. I also did not know about the `<ctrl>+<space>` shortcut, which is bascially (although not exactly) what I was looking for.

Comment: @TimHoffmann would you like to write an answer for this question?